# What is the full list of supported groovydoc tags and its syntax?

Tags: groovy, groovydoc

Does groovydoc support everything javadoc supports? Does it support the `@see`, `@code` and the `@link` tag?

This is the only thing official I could find: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_groovydoc_comment

Where is the full reference for groovydoc syntax and features?

Answer (score 1):

From the link in your question:

> Groovydoc follows the same conventions as Java’s own Javadoc. So you’ll be able to use the same tags as with Javadoc.